# When last linux turned off (blackout or manually)

Tags: logs

Is there a way to check when was the last time Linux shut down, either because of blackout or manually turned of.

The case was, my machine turned off and I don't know since when.

Comment: Yes: read the log/journal.

Comment: The `last` command is a starting point (aside from monthly rotation of its files).